# Find differences from data

Tags: mysql

I am parsing a html code at difference times. Now I want to find differences, so if any value has changed, added or deleten.

I want to save everything in a database.
The table looks like this:

```
id | column1 | column2 | column3
```

Now I want to update every row where the data has changed, added or deleten. 
What is the best way to compare the old value and the new parsed values?

Should I create a hash, and if the hash is different I delete this entry and add a new one?

Comment: define 'added' and 'deleted'

Comment: The HTML Code is a table. So I could be that one entry from that table is deleted or added. It is necessary to find exactly what row it is/was. So delete everything everytime I update the database isn't an option

Comment: 'column1', 'column2', 'column3' really don't give any idea of the content. Can you show some example data & what results you expect to get.

Comment: Once it's 'deleted', how are you going to know what it was?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily 'delete' it, I'd archive it into a separate table and that data can easily be compared using a few SQL statements.